# How to import vector drop shadow from Sketch to Android Studio

Tags: sketch-app, android

If I add a drop shadow to an asset in Sketch, then export that asset as an svg, then open that asset in Gimp, I see the shadow, so the shadow must be exporting to the svg.

However, if I import into Android Studio as vector, shadow is removed. Any idea how to reproduce the drop shadow in Android Studio vector?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely its omitted because its raster.

Comment: As far as I know, SVG drop shadow effects aren't supported in VectorDrawable. You'll need to use some other method to construct a drop shadow. Please note that coding is off-topic here. There's at least [one question with answers on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356060/how-to-add-shadow-effect-on-drawable-in-android)